# Deploy WSO2 Enterprise App Store in EC2 using ELB

Tags: amazon-ec2, wso2

I am deploying the [WSO2 Enterprise App Store](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ES100/Running+the+Product) into EC2 behind an elastic load balancer (ELB) and having some trouble getting things configured properly.

I have configured $INSTALL_PATH/repository/conf/carbon.xml with the proper HostName and MgtHostName of the ELB DNS name and I can get to the front-end of the app store and to the admin console.

I am unable to:

- get user registrations working throuth the front end app store
- get to the back-office console

The issue appears to be in routing requests to the identity service.  I get an error like the following:

```
You are now being redirected to Identity Server. If the redirection fails, please click on the button below.
```

I then get a timeout on the redirect to this RFC1918, non-routed, address:

```
https://10.x.x.x:9443/adminsamlsso
```

I see no errors in the logs on startup or throughout execution of the application.

How can I configure this application such that all requests are re-routed through the AWS ELB (not the WSO2 load balancer) and not through the direct, local, IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Please modify following configurations as well,

Update the AssertionConsumerService property for all apps(store, publisher, social) within /repository/conf/sso-idp-config.xml

You can find few jaggery apps within /repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/ directory. Each app has its own json config file within config directory.

Eg :- for store app /repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/config/store.json

You have to update the identityProviderURL property within ssoConfiguration in those apps as well.(store, publisher and social)

Comment: Hi udarakr, thanks for your response.  I updated every occurrence of identityProviderURL under repository/* to the ELB DNS name, as well as the sso-idp-config.xml localhost values, and I continue to experience the original issue.

Something is missing and continues to use the local IP value.  Any other ideas?

Comment: have you restart the ES server?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the ES server each time that I tested it.

Could this be related to the Thrift server/service?  I had previously deployed the API Manager into AWS and we had to disable the Thrift server in favor of the wsclient due to incompatibilities with the ELB configuration.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES-1.0.0 It's better if you can move to the latest 1.2.0 M2.
We also faced similar issue and now fixed in the master branch.

If you need to continue with the same 1.0.0 you can get rid of this issue by updating,

```
<ES_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/controllers/login.jag,  <ES_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher/controllers/login.jag

<ES_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/controllers/logout.jag, <ES_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher/controllers/logout.jag
```

You have to update the postUrl in above four files correctly.

NOW : `postUrl = "https://" + process.getProperty('carbon.local.ip') + ":" + process.getProperty('https.port');`

It should be something like `https://localhost:9443/`
At the end post URL should be something like `https://localhost:9443/admin/samlsso`

```
<form method="post" action="<%=postUrl%>/admin/samlsso">
```